# Combobox in a datagridview giving errors when adding a new row

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datagridview

I have problems with a comboboxcolumn in a datagridview: As I want to insert a new row, I get a "System.ArgumentException: The value of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell is invalid." I am using Linq to SQL to populate the data from different tables:

- Table Customer (ID (key), Name,...)
- Table Address (ID (key), CustomerID, Street,...)
- Table ContactPerson (ID (key), AddressID, Name, Title,...)

My Linq query to populate the ContactDataGridView(which is bound to the TextBox RelationIdTextBox), is following:

```
var y = from r in BH.Relations
   where r.RelationID.ToString() == relationIDTextBox.Text
   join v in BH.Addresss on r.RelationID equals v.RelationID
   join c in BH.ContactPersons on v.AddressID equals c.AddressID
   select c;
contactPersonsBindingSource.DataSource = y;
ContactDataGridView.DataSource = contactPersonsBindingSource;
```

This works fine.

In this ContactDataGridView I have a ComboBoxCell AddressID which populates the streetnames instead of the AddressID, using following linq query:

```
var addr = from a in BH.Addresss
   where a.RelationID.ToString() == relationIDTextBox.Text
   select new { AddressID = a.AddressID, Street = a.Street };
ContactAddressBindingSource = addr;
```

This works fine as well.

That is, untill I want to add a new row in this datagridview. Then I get the error

> "System.ArgumentException: The value of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell
>   is invalid."

Can anyone help to make me understand what I am doing wrong? I really cannot figure it out!

Comment: I tried it with other tables within my Database, and I keep getting the same errors. I noticed that I only get this error when the comboboxcell may not contain null values. Now, how can I prevent this error and let the user decide which value he wants to select from within the possible values in this combobox?

Comment: What column is kind of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`? What's the code you use to add new row?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, I solved it by setting a default value when adding a new row to the grid, That default value must be one of the existing ids in the combobox.

```
private void datagridview_base1_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Value = 1; // Cells[x] = your AdressID cell
    }
```

replace "1" with any ID that exists in Address Table, usually the one that corresponds to the first item of the combobox.